# jTable update button and add new

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Below is my code of a jFrame btn_update:

```
private void txt_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try{
        String Value1=txt_Emp_ID.getText();
        String Value2=txt_Name.getText();
        String Value3=txt_Surname.getText();
        String Value4=txt_age.getText();
        String Value5=txt_Username.getText();
        String Value6=txt_Password.getText();

        String sql = "update employee set Emp_ID=?, name=?,surname=?,age=?,username=?,password=?";           
        pst.setString(1, Value1);
        pst.setString(2, Value2);
        pst.setString(3, Value1);
        pst.setString(4, Value1);
        pst.setString(5, Value1);
        pst.setString(6, Value1);
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated!!");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

and my configurations:

```
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
```

when I try to press the update button I get this:

> java.sql.SQLException:Parameter index out of Range (2>number of parameters, which is 1)
>   can someone help me?

Comment: 1) You should call `conn.prepareStatement(sql)` *before* set its parameters. 2) You set `Value1` to all the parameters in your prepared statement which is not probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues

- Your exception message indicates that the `PreparedStatement` only has 2 parameters. Assign the variable before setting the parameters
- Copy/paste error where parameters 3-6 are all `Value1` instead of `Value3`, `Value4`, etc.
- `executeQuery` is used to query the database. Use `executeUpdate` for database write operations

Result:

```
preparesStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparesStatement.setString(1, value1);
...// etc.
preparesStatement.setString(6, value6);
```

Comment: i did that and now i get the following error:
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: Use `int rows = pst.executeUpdate();`